# Azure AD Authentication of Angular app with MVC Core on Azure AppService

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-graph-api, adal.js, msal.js

I'm investigating options for adding AzureAD authentication to Angular SPA application with .NET core backend. I'm using VS 2019 MVC project with Angular (same as `dotnet new Angular` is producing). It's using .NET Core 3.1 and Angular 8.

From what I learned so far I have 3 options:

1. [Built in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-auth-aad) Azure App Service Authentication
2. [Adal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) - looks like the older brother of,
3. [MSAL.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal) - which after making it work locally with Azure AD I learned on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) that **"At this time, AAD V2 (including MSAL) is not supported for Azure App Services and Azure Functions. Please check back for updates."** I couldn't make it work on Azure today so maybe this Note is for a good reason.

EDIT: Interestingly now point 3 works for me on Azure App Service so I'm not sure what this note means.

My requirements so far are that no screen is accessible to users unless they log in and that I will be able to read information about them from Azure AD - Roles, groups.
I never worked with Angular and I don't have any experience with Azure AD and I need someone that implemented it already to at least tell me which option I should choose and I can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

> My requirements so far are that no screen is accessible to users unless they log in and that I will be able to read information about them from Azure AD - Roles, groups.

I think the option 1 could meet your requirement, the configuration of Azure AD in `Authentication / Authorization` is higher than your code, the user could not access the app unless they log in.

To read the information about the `roles`, `groups`, you could check this good [blog](https://joonasw.net/view/using-groups-vs-using-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps).

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an angular E2E auth scenario using App Service built in authentication:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-auth-aad

I believe the part you are interested in is this one:
[Enable authentication and authorization for front-end app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-auth-aad#enable-authentication-and-authorization-for-front-end-app)

This way app service is the one redirecting you to AAD and getting a valid token that you can just pass in to your APIs afterwards. If the APIs are hosted in App Service as well, then APP service will be the one validating the token for you, so your backend code does not need to worry about authentication (you still need to handle authorization)